# Post interactive HTML content to user wall

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-wall

Can I post interactive HTML content (such as a Form with a couple of options - Yes/No) to a user's wall on Facebook?

Also, I may want to POST something back to my own website when the user clicks, without the user having to navigate away from Facebook.

Comment: Hey, wondering the same here. Do you have an update? or you go with SWF? Does it serve what you want?
cheers

Answer (score 1):

No; the post only allows text (and makes thumbnails from links automatically).

On the other hand, you could make a Facebook app which allows various interactions beyond "follow this link".

Comment: If you want my opinion, that's a Good Thing: I'm tired of all the XSS and XSRF issues arising from allowing untrusted input (such as HTML content).

Comment: You can post SWF files but they're limited in how they can interact with the browser chrome or other parts of the page

Comment: You can even pass parameters to the swf and individualize it.

Comment: I didn't find it in the docs. I have found this solution somewhere here on stackoverflow as far as I remember, however I can't find it anymore. I have tried it out already on production and it works. If you like, you can post a question and I'll share my code.

Comment: @Lego: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517458/how-to-post-flash-applets-to-a-wall-on-facebook