# How to post Flash applets to a wall on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, flash

In the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507289/post-interactive-html-content-to-user-wall), users have commented that it's possible to insert a Flash applet into a Facebook wall post. I was under the impression this isn't possible without making a FB app.

I'm aware that FB will convert links to various media types - e.g. a link to a MP3 becomes automagically a SWF MP3 player, but the Flash applet used is chosen by FB's internal logic, not by the content of the post. Is it possible to embed a SWF applet *of your own choosing*?

As I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, has anyone else? Or, do you have some PoC code that does this?

Comment: Allegedly, this has been answered here on SO, so this may be a duplicate question; alas, my search skills fail me here (as well as on the Internet at large).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in the comment of the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507313/601466), that you were also interested in how to pass parameters to the swf, here is the solution:

**in javascript**

```
function postOnWall(fbuid) {
    var params = {};
    params['message'] = "my message";
    params['name'] = "my name";
    params['description'] = "my description";
    params['link'] = "https://www.mylink.com";
    params['caption'] = "my caption";
    params['picture'] = "https://www.mylink.de/thumb.png";
    params['source'] = "https://www.mylink.de/Main.swf" + "?bla=thisisyourdynamicquerystring";

    FB.api('/' + fbuid + '/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            // Error occured while publishing to stream
        } else {
            // Published to stream
        }
    });
}
```

**in actionscript**

```
public function Main() {    
    this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
}

private function loaderComplete(event : Event) : void {
    var myQueryStrings : Object = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
    if (myQueryStrings && myQueryStrings.bla) {
        _myMovie.label.text = myQueryStrings.bla;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the Facebook's JS-SDK for it:

```
     FB.ui(
       {
         method: 'feed',
         name: 'Title pf post',
         link: 'http://link.to.target',
         picture: 'http://link.to.previewimage',
         source: 'http://link.to.swf',
         caption: 'Subtitle',
         description: 'Maintext',
       },
       function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) {
           //alert('Post was published.');
         } else {
           //alert('Post was not published.');
         }
       }
     );
```

Comment: poor choice of wording... JS-SDK was meant. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ and in special https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: Thanks for the correction. FB keeps changing the SDKs as regularly as a snake shedding its skin.